# TPagecontrol equivalent for Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

while changing  software development from VCL frame work to Firemonkey, I can not understand where is the TPagecontrol component gone from the good old VCL framework.

I already placed a TTabControl on my Form and added several Tabitemn, bit now I can not find the replacement for the TPagecontrol.

Answer (score 14):

You can take Firemonkey's [`TTabControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.TabControl.TTabControl) as a replacement for VCL's [`TPageControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl). Their tabs are containers just like everything else in Firemonkey (so unlike the VCL's [`TTabControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabControl) their tabs are real containers).

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks for this Info.  I placed a Tmemo on the first TTablControl but could see is on all TTabscontrols. Will now check on the problem

Comment: Show the structure pane in your IDE (SHIFT + ALT + F11). It is certainly a must to have it shown for designing Firemonkey applications. There you will clearly see where the memo is really placed and there you can optionally "drag" it to the tab item.